# Why to create and use a Samsung account (on a brand-new S4 mini)?

Tags: samsung

Are there any real benefits of (creating and) using a Samsung account? Or is Samsung just offering inferior services (e.g. "synch") in an effort to deepen its marketing clout?

Comment: I haven't really seen any good use for activating the Samsung account. It will just add more stress to your phone (syncs, notifications), but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Personally, I haven't created a Samsung account, and rooted my S4 to remove all the samsung apps (hubs, etc.) With all the Android ecosystem, I don't really see a benefit in the Samsung layer. But that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

As well as getting access to Samsung's sync and backup service, creating a Samsung account also gets you access to Samsung's app store. It's not as extensive as the main Play Store, but it has a good selection of apps.

Whether you think that's a "real benefit" or not is entirely up to you.